Userscript Can't Run on Google Search Console Pages?
I'm trying to create a script which will allow the exclusion of certain results on the "not indexed" page of Google Search Console, to alleviate reviewing things repeatedly.
Violentmonkey reports the script is active on the specified inclusion page, but I can't get any code to fire. Console doesn't report anything as far as a block on userscripts. Any insights appreciated
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Index Excludes
// @include https://search.google.com/search-console/index/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// @require     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/arrive/2.4.1/arrive.min.js
// @version 1
// ==/UserScript==

alert('got script');
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('got script');
    document.body.arrive('.nJ0sOc',{fireOnAttributesModification:true,existing:true,onceOnly:true},function(){
    
        console.log('got row');
        $(this).prepend("<td class='exclude'><a href='#'>X</a></td>");
    });
});


I think the issue is with the include path being https://search.google.com/search-console/index/* ... since the actual page is https://search.google.com/search-console/index?.... - i.e. the /* means it doesn't match the current page

@JaromandaX Thanks, but if ViolentMonkey reports a script is active, it means the inclusion targeting is correct for the page. I changed it to index* and it is the same result
Plus, on my end, the URL is: https://search.google.com/search-console/index/drilldown?resource_id=

check the console; jquery is crashing the script (TrustedHTML error)
